# web browser developer tools

Tags: web-services, web, developer-tools

I have a question. Not sure im even allowed to post it here but in new and i guess I'll find out. I was on my email and i for some reason felt as tho is go into the dev tools on my web brower even tho i have no idea how to use them. I began looking around and then came the the network part of it where i was seeing some website pop up i then decided to type one in to the web browser on new tap and when i did it cam back just black. And the site at the top was long like the one i typed init was only ssl.gstatic.com. the full URL i typed looked like this. https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/cleardot.gif?zx=wgd121l02lwv. There are lots more of these kind of URLs coming in.

Answer (score 0):

That image is a 1x1 pixel transparent dot, which is why you can't see it. Typically these are used to log that you visited a particular site or opened an email.

gstatic.com is a Google site which you can verify by clicking on the padlock to the left of the URL and examining the site's certificates.

This is probably a normal part of making a Google marketing mail or Gmail work for you. Unless you are particularly concerned that Google is tracking you, you don't need to be concerned about this.

Comment: See i have no idea what u just said to do. Ok the one https web address i have listed when i typed it in it came back as a web page no error on it nothing it had the address ssl.gstatic.com in the top and the page was black. Are u saying save it as a pdf file? And if this is just an image which i have a feeling there is more to it. Should i be worried about these sites if not can i remove this traffic and stop it from coming in?

Comment: Ok i saved it...well shared it to my Google drive cuz i didn't have an option to save as. I went to Google drive viewed it there and a couple other apps and it came back either a white or black background with the web address i typed in displayed in it.

Comment: You don't need to worry about it. gstatic.com is a Google site. You can look at the site's certificate by clicking on the green padlock next to the address and verify this.